# How can I reset navigation delegate, after switching between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, skmaps

Navigation starts, all the delegate methods are set and everything works as intended.

But if a user switches to another ViewController, while navigation is still on, and returns to the navigation view controller, something happens with the navigation delegate, and all navigation delegate methods are unresponsive.

I of course tried setting them again

```
[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].navigationDelegate = self;
```

even tried setting them first to nil and then setting them to self again

```
[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].navigationDelegate = nil;
[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].navigationDelegate = self;
```

But it doesn't work.

So my questions are:

Can I even set the navigation delegate, after the navigation has started?

What could be the general cause of the ViewController "loosing" delegate?

P.S. I tried not setting delegates to another view controller, when I switch between them (even though I have a map on that other one as well, but didn't work out). As soon as I change my NavigationView controller by segueing to another one, navigationDelegate methods become unresponsive.

Comment: well you don’t need to  set then again because  it has to work  maybe switching is  not a problem here  can you  please show the detail  code of switching to viewconttroler and  returning back  so I can help you

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in the demo project and attach the modified version to this question? More data is needed before we can understand your flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, apparently It had nothing to do with the delegates but the fact that I didn't know I had to start navigation again, once I got returned to the Screen where navigation was on.

As I would transfer to the second screen, where I had another map, I could see that the user cursor was moving, so I assumed that navigation was still on, as the map is a singleton.

But in the end, starting navigation again with solved the issue

```
SKNavigationSettings* navSettings = [SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings];

    navSettings.navigationType=SKNavigationTypeSimulation;
    //navSettings.navigationType = SKNavigationTypeReal;

    navSettings.distanceFormat=SKDistanceFormatMilesFeet;
    navSettings.zoomLevelConfigurations = nil;
    [SKRoutingService sharedInstance].mapView.settings.displayMode = SKMapDisplayMode3D;

    [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance]startNavigationWithSettings:navSettings];
```